# How to find the element present in Another Div from Jquery

Tags: jquery

How to find the element of other Div

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div>
      <a class="txt">Some text</a>
    </div>


    <div>
      <a class="txt">Some text</a>
      <button id="button"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".button").bind("mouseover", function () {
    $(this).siblings(".txt").text("some more text"));
});
```

it works fine if the element is present in same Div, but if i want to catch the element that is present in different div then it will not work (obviously) so.. any answer how to make it work?

Comment: You need to find the correct combination of [traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/). In this specific case, I might use something like `$(this).parent().prev().children('.txt')`

Comment: **Disclaimer: I am the author.** You might find this useful in this case: http://techfoobar.com/jquery-next-in-dom/ - In this case, use it like `$(this).prevInDOM('.txt');`

Comment: You could also solve this problem by using a class or data attribute to identify the pair. For example, if the second text contains some details relating to the first, you might use `class="txt details"` or `data-type="details"`.

Comment: there is now element with class button.. could you please be more specific?

Comment: @Alex agree, even it's not that hard to figure it here ;)

Comment: `$(this).closest('div').siblings('div').find('.txt').text('some more text');` this way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/Bh3Ex/

You need to find the specific DOM traversion methods for your particular case. Like this:

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('.txt').text("some more text");
```

[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

There are several others, such as [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/), but you will need to find the ones that apply to your use case.

Edit: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good link, I didnt know that existed. I'll add it to the answer. Glad it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this, using a more maintanable way:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CB4vg/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
      <a class="txt">Some text</a>
    </div>   
    <div>
      <button class="button"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".button").on("mouseover", function () { //or still use bind depending your jQuery version
    $(this).closest(".container").find('.txt').text("some more text");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$(this).siblings(".txt").text("some more text"));
```

to this:

```
$(this).closest('div').siblings('div').find('.txt').text('some more text');
```